# Why host is not hitting web app in docker container even with -P option?

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. I built an image with spring-roo project installed in tomcat server.

```
docker run -P manojp1988/spring-roo
```

Above image is published to dockerhub. But my problem is , i could not access the webapp from my host machine.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
b97ac7dd0a96        manojp1988/spring-roo   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /git/"   15 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:32778->5000/tcp   elated_meitner
```

http://localhost:32778/roo

Even though i give `-P` i couldnt connect with the webapp. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`-P` publishes to a random port. Try `-p 5000:5000` to ensure port 5000 from the container is mapped to port 5000 on the host.

Noticed you were using the random port so I'm amending my answer.
Start the container with `--net=host` so that the port is accessible from the host's IP.

Comment: I tried " docker run -P 5000:5000 manojp1988/spring-roo"  & " docker run --net=host manojp1988/spring-roo" but didnt work. 

Did you try in your machine? I am using docker app in MAC.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i did is I have downloaded tomcat image and I configured on top. So whenever i give -P, the host port is connected to 8080 in container. Tomcat also deployed my app in 8080, so it is working.

Earlier i have used maven image and used embedded tomcat plugin. So when i connect my host, host port is always mapped to 5000. Don't know this is the reason.